# Problem with displaying Y axis title and x axis title using google chart and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, css, charts, google-visualization

i have some CSS problem related to displaying of Google chart , The problem is i am not able to view x axis title and values and also y axis title comes in middle of chart .

[image: My Chart]

and here is my code :

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['bar']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

function drawStuff() {
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>);

  var options = {
    width: 800,
    height: 700,

    // legend: { position: 'none' },
    axisTitlesPosition: {
      position: 'out'
    },
    title: 'Outside Temperature',
    curveType: 'none',
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    chartArea: {
      top: 0,
      height: 200
    },
    hAxis: {
      slantedText: true,
      slantedTextAngle: 90
    },
    chart: {
      title: 'BA',
      subtitle: ''
    },
    axes: {
      x: {
        0: {
          side: 'bottom',
          label: 'TOTAL LOADS CREATED'
        } // Top x-axis.
      },
      y: {
        0: {
          side: 'left',
          label: 'MONTH YEAR'
        } // Top x-axis.
      }
    },
    bar: {
      groupWidth: "50%"
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
  // Convert the Classic options to Material options.
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}; <
/script>
```

```css
 .panel {
            padding: 0 18px;
            display: none;
            background-color: white;
            overflow: hidden;
            }
```

```html
<button class="accordion">ABSC</button>
<div class="panel">

  <?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'testingoforiginal');
 =$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `loads created per month`");
  if($result){
  echo "";
}
                                                
$data = array();
$data[] = ['Month YEAR', 'TOTAL LOADS CREATED'];
                                                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
                                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                                    $data[] = [$row['Month YEAR'], $row['TOTAL LOADS CREATED']];
}
}
?>
    <div id="top_x_div" style="width: 800px; height: 800px;"></div>
```

here when i click button(Colapsible button) it will open up the panel . i don't understand what is the reason for showing the axis in middle and not showing the x axis value and title .

Comment: you need to wait until the panel is visible before drawing the chart for the first time. this is a known issue. when the chart's container is not visible, the chart cannot properly calculate the position of chart elements. where is the code that shows the panel?

Comment: i solved it , it  was CSS issue